# Woocommerce Flexslider touch functionality on desktop not working

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, jquery

I am using Flexslider settings in Woocommerce to modify the image slider on the single product page.
https://woocommerce.com/flexslider/
Support for this is added into Woocommerce by default.

I have entered the below code into my functions.php in order to set 'touch' to true and enable finger swiping on touch devices. 
I have confirmed that this works on a mobile device. However this doesnt work on my Surface Pro 3 (also a touch device). 
It works only when in Chrome DevTools, if I press the device size toggle and then press refresh. However when I close DevTools and refresh again, it stops working.

```
add_filter("woocommerce_single_product_carousel_options", "change_flexslider_options", 10);
function change_flexslider_options($options) {
$options = array(
  'rtl' => is_rtl(), 
  'animation' => 'slide', 
  'smoothHeight' => false, 
  'directionNav' => true,  
  'controlNav' => true,
  'slideshow' => false, 
  'animationSpeed' => 500, 
  'animationLoop' => false,
  'touch' => true,
);
return $options;
}
```

I am not sure how to have flexslider recognise whether the desktop is or isnt a touch device.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! We don't support plugins here - the plugin authors often offer the best support available, so you will likely need to contact Automattic. From what you've described, it sounds like their code is identifying certain screen sizes as "mobile" (touch-enabled) rather than using "hover" and "pointer" queries, so you may wish to reference those in your support ticket asking if they can update their method of device detection.

Comment: I’ve had no luck with Automattic. You can only contact them for support if you are a paid user. Not sure what the difference is, besides getting support that is . Ive noticed if I enable Touch events API in chrome settings it works. Why wouldnt this be enabled anyway? Could code enable this for the site visitors browser?

Comment: You could raise a GitHub issue/request. They aren't always quick to reply, but that would bring it to their attention and if they recognize it has value for many of their users they could update their query. You may also want to look at Google Analytics to see if you can determine how many visitors are using devices like this, that don't come up as "mobile" but do have touch support. You may find it's a low number so you don't have to worry about it other than it affecting you.

Comment: Thanks WebElaine. I raised the issue on GitHub. My site isn’t live yet but good point, the numbers probably aren’t very high.